# Dynamically changing the structure of a grid React

Tags: javascript, css

I've been given a react project recently that requires me to render out a grid of DIVs. rendering the DIVs is fine but finding a way to change the amount of columns wide dynamically seems to be a challenge. I had originally thought i could apply a function that would take the amount from a text box and dynamically change the amount of rows wide in the CSS but  that seems not to be possible.

My question is there a way of doing this in react or is there a library that would make this allot more convenient.(Baring in mind I wasn't aware of react a month ago.)

Comment: this is not a react native related question

Comment: This has been amended.

Answer (score 0):

> Rows wide

I assume you mean the number of columns here?

Can you get the length of the number of columns?

If so, something like this should help out.

```
`{[...Array(yourLength).keys()].map((key) => (
  return(<div className={key+" key based css"}></div>)
  )}
```

Comment: The idea would be that the number of columns wide would be based on a text-box.